# Obter próximo registro em um foreach agrupado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu poderia estar selecionando o próximo registro dentro de um `foreach` agrupado antes de ele terminar, sem avançar nesse *loop*?

O ponto aonde penso que poderia estar obtendo essa informação é onde está escrito **OBTER O PRÓXIMO ID DESSE FOREACH** no código abaixo:

```
decimal? valor = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model.Lista.GroupBy(d => d.Nome)
                              .Select(
                               g => new
                               {
                                 key = g.Key,
                                 Id = g.First().Id,
                                 NomeFantasia = g.First().NomeFantasia,
                                 ValorTotal = g.Sum(s => s.ValorTotal) }))
{
   <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Valor</td>
   </tr>

   valor += item.Valor;

   <!- **OBTER O PRÓXIMO ID DESSE FOREACH** -->

}

   <tr>
     <td colspan="2"></td>
     <td>@Valor</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que deseja, mas no fim do laço virá o próximo `id`. VoCê quer o próximo antes de terminar? Não seria melhor colocar o LINQ no *controller*, na *view* deveria ter só código estritamente necessário para gerar a *view*, esse código de LINQ é regras de sistema, ou mesmo eu diria regra de negócio, que deveria estar no *model*.

Comment: Exato. eu gostaria de obter o próximo antes de terminar. sim. concordo e deve o LINQ estar no controller, porém surgiu um problema e tive que implementar assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode usar o `for each` quando quer controlar o índice, por isso existe o `for`:

```
var valor = 0M;
@foreach (var i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    valor += model[i].Valor;
    var proximoID = model[i + 1].Id;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ForTemplate.cs).

Comment: qual o tipo desse model ? setei o model pra List<>. porém não tá vindo o length :

Comment: ao invés de utilizar o model.length, usei o model.Count(); ai funcionou. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: É o que você fez eu só evitei de colocar aí, e eu errei nisso mesmo vou consertar :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um contador para ser o índice das iterações e usar o valor `i+1` para acessar a sua lista.

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach(...)
{
    <span>@i+1</span>

    i++;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
var lista = Model.Lista.GroupBy(d => d.Nome)
                          .Select(
                           g => new
                           {
                             key = g.Key,
                             Id = g.First().Id,
                             NomeFantasia = g.First().NomeFantasia,
                             ValorTotal = g.Sum(s => s.ValorTotal) });

@{decimal? valor = 0;int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in )
{
   <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Valor</td>
   </tr>

   valor += item.Valor;

   <!- **OBTER O PRÓXIMO ID DESSE FOREACH** -->
   lista[i++].Id
}
```

Comment: não é isso não. eu gostaria de obter o próximo antes de terminar o foreach

Comment: Você tem o índice atual, o proxímo elemento vai ser o Lista[i+1] ... Sendo que `Lista` é a variavel que você vai atribuir o seu `GroupBy` e depois da rforeach nessa mesma variável. Lamentável o downvote.